# Facebook Graph API - Image post not showing on page news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been using the Graph API of Facebook and for the publication of images, notice that the entire publication process is done correctly, whether it is a single image or a set of images, everything works well and I am the administrator of the page of Facebook I can observe the publications, but when I do it from any other account no longer.

In summary, I can post images and observe them from the administrator account, but everything appears hidden to the public.

The permissions my token has are: manage_pages, publish_pages, pages_show_list, publish_to_groups

I have read the documentation but I have not been able to find any errors in my tests:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Do I need to have the application verified by Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for all the public to see the images published it is necessary that the application go to active mode, so it is recommended that it be sent for verification.